# Getting one or more sub-categories in Wordpress - is merge of arrays possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, array-merge

I have written some code that uses the Wordpress get_terms function to display a list of sub-categories for a user-defined category and also shows the relevant thumbnail for each sub-category. As far as I'm aware, there isn't a WP function to display all child categories across multiple parents, so I was wondering if it's possible to merge the results of two or more get_terms results?

The code I have written so far is working fine to get_terms from just one parent category but I'm not sure where to go from here…

```
function get_wc_child_cat_thumbs($catParent, $listClassName) {

    // Our wordpress get_terms arguments
    $args = array(
        'number'        => $number,
        'orderby'       => $orderby,
        'order'         => $order,
        'hide_empty'    => $hide_empty,
        'include'       => $ids,
        'parent'        => $catParent,
    );

    // Get the terms
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

    // See if any results are returned
    $count = count($product_categories);

    // If there are, populate a list with the subcategories details
    if ( $count > 0 ){
        echo '<ul class="'.$listClassName.'">';
        foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {

            // Get the thumbnail id for the subcategory
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $product_category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

            // Show the results…
            echo '<li>'.wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id ).'<br />'.$product_category->term_id.' - <a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></li>';

            //echo $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id );
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    } // END if ( $count > 0 ){

} // END function get_wc_child_cat_thumbs`
```

Is it possible to change the `$catParent` argument so that it accepts either single or array values and add in an array_merge somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
$product_categories = array();
foreach ($catParent as $parent) {
    $args = array(
        'number'        => $number,
        'orderby'       => $orderby,
        'order'         => $order,
        'hide_empty'    => $hide_empty,
        'include'       => $ids,
        'parent'        => $parent,
    );

    // Get the terms
    $categories = get_terms('product_cat', $args );
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $product_categories[] = $category;
    }
}
```

assuming `$catParent` is an array

edit second foreach

```
foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        // Get the thumbnail id for the subcategory
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $product_category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

        // Show the results…
        echo '<li>'.wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id ).'<br />'.$product_category->term_id.' - <a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></li>';

        //echo $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id );
}
```

Comment: Hi @RST, if I change the code and add an array to my function call like so `get_wc_child_cat_thumbs(array(415,418), 'testlist');`I get the following error…

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in`

Comment: Did you adjust the `foreach` loop you already had in there? Instead of one `array` it is an `array` of `arrays` now. With a double `foreach` it should work.

Comment: No, I didn't try that - I'm not sure how to write it :-(

Comment: Great stuff - that's working thank you :-) The second array is added at the end though and I'd like all subcategories to be merged so I can sort the whole lot alphabetically. Is an array merge needed for this to happen?

Comment: You can manipulate `$product_categories` before the second `foreach` happens, or flatten the `$product_categories` array to a one-dimensional array. There are always more ways to do things. Adjusted the code.

Comment: Have tried array_merge like `foreach ( $product_categories as $values ) {
   
   $mergeResults = array_merge($values);` but still having the same problem - Never flattened an array before

Comment: It has merged all the different sub-categories but looks like it's made an infinite loop - you can see the results at http://findyourdreamdress.co.uk/ - the grid of products at the bottom is what I'm doing

Comment: It is not an infinite loop. You seem to have multiple categories with the same name. See if you can remove the (semi)duplicates. Search this forum or the internet for information on array handling. Submit a new ticket with adjusted code.

Comment: Thanks @RST, I've managed to sort it now - I merged the arrays and used usort to change the order using one of the array values. Thanks very much for you help, very much appreciated. I'll post the final code here for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort the problem (literally) with great help from @RST. In the end I merged the multiple arrays and sorted the results alphabetically using usort and the name value from the array as the comparison. Here's the finished code…

```
// Used instead of brands plugin - was duplicating content
function get_multiple_woocommerce_child_cats($catParent, $listClassName) {

    $product_categories = array();
    foreach ($catParent as $parent) {
        $args = array(
            'number'        => $number,
            'orderby'       => $orderby,
            'order'         => $order,
            'hide_empty'    => $hide_empty,
            'include'       => $ids,
            'parent'        => $parent,
        );

        // Get the terms
        $product_categories[] = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    }

    // See if any results were returned
    $count = count($product_categories);

    // If there are, populate a list with the subcategories details
    if ( $count > 0 ){

        // Merge the separate product category arrays into one big array
        $mergedcats = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $product_categories);

        // Function to sort the array by name value. Need to use the class operator in Wordpress $a->name instead of $a['name'] otherwise we get an error
        function sorteed($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
        }

        // Sort the big array by the category name value
        usort($mergedcats, sorteed);

        // For testing…
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($result);
        //echo"</pre>";

        // Print out the results in the desired format      
        echo '<ul class="'.$listClassName.'">';
            foreach ( $mergedcats as $product_category ) {

                // Get the thumbnail id for the subcategory
                $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $product_category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

                // Show the results…
                echo '  <li>
                            <div>
                                <a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">'.wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id ).'</a>
                            </div>
                            <p>Cat id is - '.$product_category->term_id.'</p><p> Cat name is - <a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></p>
                        </li>';
            } // END foreach

        echo '</ul>';

    } else {}

} // END function get_wc_child_cat_thumbs
```